# What was the reason for Trump's administration to withdraw from JCPOA?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, iran, jcpoa

From the Wikipedia article for [JCPOA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action):

> After the Trump administration twice certified Iran's compliance in 2017, in May 2018 the United States withdrew from JCPOA as Trump pledged he would negotiate a better deal. Trump left office without fulfilling that pledge and analysts determined Iran had moved closer to developing a nuclear weapon since the American withdrawal.

Trump and his staff for sure knew Iran's regime wouldn't accept to meet the Americans to negotiate about a new deal. So I don't think that's the reason. Of course, maybe Trump thought Khamenei is another Kim Jong-un and the two can meet!

The only other reason I can think about is that Trump administration thought Iran would continue its efforts to make atomic bombs whether with or without the deal. So it would be better that there is no deal at all... But according to the quoted text Trump administration twice certified Iran's compliance before.

Also, there's this quote by Trump in this [PoliticalFact](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/promises/trumpometer/promise/1368/renegotiate-iran-deal/) article:

> “This deal if I win will be a totally different deal. This will be a totally different deal.”

Trump wasn't sure about his reelection, let alone making a new deal after winning.

So what was the reason for Trump administration to withdraw from JCPOA?

Comment: I consider it problematic to try and analyze the decisions of the Trump administration separate from analyzing the personal mind of Donald Trump, and the latter is out of scope on this board. *Other* administrations might have had a systematic policy process, Trump had Trump.

Comment: Trump has on a number of occasion done precisely the same thing - pretended he's DEAL MAKER EXTRAORDINAIRE.  And torn shit up.  NAFTA comes to mind.  And acted irrationally from the PoV of many.  JCPOA was compromise from the get go, everyone had to give up something, so there's a sizable portions of American who hated compromise w Iran.  **Trump doesn't work that way.**  VTC.  And -1, just out of general dislike for the "what's the real reason?" type of questions.  You certainly haven't given any real reason to have this Q.

Comment: Asking the "**real** reason" seems to ask for a degree of certainty that is hard to achieve. We either take at face value the declarations of the people involved in the decision (which implies trusting their honesty), or have to rely on expert *opinion* (which is an opinion and can easily be wrong because insufficient information, bias...). And that is without taking into consideration, well, Trump.

Comment: @o.m. Trump for sure seeked his government's advices regarding his decisions. If he always heard the voice of his own mind and didn't pay attention to his staff's advices we should have seen the staff resign in protest for Trump's toxic narcissistic nature.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I have edited the question and removed the words *real*.

Comment: @SnackExchange  Txs, and apologies for being aggressive.  But, even in normal cases it is often difficult to satisfy valid curiosity that goes beyond official explanations given.  Now in the case of Iran - a country whose leadership I too find rather toxic - the US, as a whole, seems prone to irrational emotive behavior.  There's a saying, "you can choose your friends, but not your enemies"  The US while it has some valid points about Iran often can't hold balanced expectations.  Add Tr. to the equation and you have an even more weird dynamic.  So what got him to make his decision?  Who knows?

Comment: Trump's stated that he set out to "undo everything Obama did", the JCPOA being something Obama did, no further explanation is needed.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica While I accept that Iran's regime is toxic I didn't use the word toxic for Iran. I used it for Trump in that comment.